# Is it safe to remove duplicate indexes in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

In my MySQL database I have a table called wp_bp_document from a wordpress site, I did a "CHECK TABLE `wp_bp_document`" and I realized that it has duplicate indexes

I don't know if it's safe to keep those duplicate indexes or if it's better to remove them.

In your experience what should I do with it?

[image]